# Keep position of D3 graph after updating data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have the following problem. I created a graph in D3. I added a dropdown menu where the nodes of the graph get resized according to the chosen category. To do that I wrote a function that re-runs the javascript code every time I choose an option in the dropdown menu. 
However, the updated graph appears at the end of my website. Is there a way to keep the graph at its original position ? 
I tried to put it in a div and fix the position, but that didn't work out. I hope my problem is clear.

Find in the following a toy example of my code.

Cheers!

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">

</style>


</head>
<body>

<select onchange="change(this)">
  <option value="rad1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="rad2">Option 2</option>
</select>   

<p> This is some text above the plot </p>

<script type="text/javascript">

change('rad1')

function change(dd) {
  update(dd.value)
}

function update(rad) {

  var current = rad;

  d3.selectAll('svg').remove();


  var w = 500;
  var h = 300;


  var dataset = { 
      nodes: [
        { name:'Node 1',rad1:  1.31, rad2: 2.32  },
        { name:'Node 2',rad1:  2.12, rad2: 5.00  },
        { name:'Node 3',rad1: 40.30, rad2: 20.40 }
        ],
      edges: [
        { source:0, target:0,rad1:  3.31 },
        { source:0, target:1,rad1:  3.31},
        { source:1, target:2,rad1:  20.31}
        ]
    };


  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(dataset.nodes)
    .links(dataset.edges)
    .size([w, h])
    .linkDistance([100])
    .charge([-300])
    .start();

  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(dataset.edges)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .style("stroke", "#808080")
    .style("stroke-width", 1)
    .style("stroke-opacity", 0.1);


var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { 
      if( current == "rad1") {
        return d.rad1;
      } else {
        return d.rad2;
      }
    })
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return '#000000';
    })
    .call(force.drag)
    .on("click", function(d) {
        console.log("Name: " + d.name);
    });


force.on("tick", function() {

  edges.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  nodes.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

});


}

</script>

<p> Here is more text below the plot </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are appending the SVG to the body, thus it will always show at the very end of the page. The correct way is creating a div (or anything else) with an ID (which are unique):

```
<div id="svghere"></div>
```

And then appending the SVG:

```
var svg = d3.select("#svghere")
    .append("svg")
    .//the rest of the code
```

Comment: When you say "I tried to put it in a div", did you try this way?

Comment: Perfect this solves the problem. No, I did something else. I put it in a div and changed the position in the css ...

Comment: Great! Just remember: classes can be shared, but IDs are unique. You can't have anything else in this HTML with the same ID.